# How to write bash script while using command as condition in if statement?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

I am writing a bash script to process input from html form.

First problem is that I can't get my if statement to work while using command as condition. I am trying to check user input of middle initial and adjust it to make sure it can be combined into $answer.

Here is example of how it is suppose to process.

User inputs three different fields from html form; first name, middle initial, last name.

First name : George
Middle Initial : W.
Last name : Bush

Shell script will process and compare user input and actual answer.
Actual answer is "George W. Bush"

User input:
George W. Bush = correct echo "You are correct!"
George W Bush = correct by automatically placing period after "W"
George Bush != wrong and echo "No middle initial!"
Geor W. Bus != wrong and echo "First name and last name are wrong!"

```
#! /bin/bash
echo Content-type: "text/html"
echo ""

read input #name variable $first, $middle, $last name

first=`user input`
middle=`user input`
last=`user input`

president=`actual answer, full name of president`
answer=`user answer, combination of $first, $middle, $last`

correctF=`actual first name from $president`
correctM=`actual middle initial from $president`
correctL=`actual last name from $president`
#cut by column from $president
```

First problem starts here.

```
if [[ $(echo $middle | wc -l) = 1 ]] ; then
    middle=`echo "$middle""."` 
    #check if middle initial variable was entered with just the letter and place a period after
elif [[ $(echo $middle | grep '.') = 'true' ]] ; then
    middle=`echo "$middle"`
    #check if middle initial variable was entered with the period and leave it as is
else
    middle=`'false'`
    #no middle initial variable was entered and is null
fi
```

Second problem in while loop with if statement.

I am trying to compare the user input $answer to actual answer $president and echo what is wrong with $answer. Nothing is echoed for this section.

```
while [ "$president" -ne "$answer" ] #not working
    do
            if [ "$first" -ne "$correctF" ]
                    then
                            echo "Wrong first name!"
            elif [ "$middle" -ne "$correctM" ]
                    then
                            echo "Wrong middle initial!"
            elif [ "$last" -ne "$correctL" ]
                    then
                            echo "Wrong last name!"
            elif [ -z "$middle" -ne "$correctM" ]
                    then
                            echo "No middle initial!"
            elif [ "$first" -ne "$correctF" ] && [ "$last" -ne "$correctL" ]
                    then
                            echo "Wrong first and last name!"
            elif [ "$first" -ne "$correctF" ] && [ "$middle" -ne "$correctM" ]
                    then
                            echo "Wrong first name and middle initial!"
            elif [ "$middle" -ne "$correctM" ] && [ "$last" -ne "$correctL" ]
                    then
                            echo "Wrong middle initial and last name!"
            elif [ "$first" -ne "$correctF" ] && [ "$middle" -ne "$correctM"] && [ "$last" -ne "$correctL" ]
                    then
                            echo "You got it all wrong!"
                    else
                            echo "You are correct!"
            fi
```

I need to properly implement a command into if statement condition and write a if statement with multiple conditions.

Comment: Please add the input you get and the result you expect.

Comment: This script has so much wrong with it that I don't even know where to begin....except maybe with: **if this script is meant to process input from a HTML form, then do some basic research on writing CGI scripts before you write any code**

Comment: I've included examples of how it is suppose to process and show result. It is suppose to process input from a HTML form. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So what happens if I enter "You suck; rm -fr /" as first name?

Comment: Agree with @cas.  James, if you are processing input from an HTML form using this script, you are right now laying your server *wide open* to total destruction.

Comment: @Henrik well that is too advanced for me. I am just trying to write a simple script expecting user to input 2 or 3 fields.

Comment: @Wildcard this is just a small project done on amazon nod.

Comment: Is it an internet-facing project?  Is your server locked down for your own personal use only?

Comment: @James:  As you say and your code shows, you're a beginner.  You might as well start off properly and learn tools suitable to web programming such as PHP.

Comment: Hardly anyone writes CGI scripts using `sh` or `bash`, and those that do usually move on quickly to a more capable/suitable language like `perl` or `python`.  But if you're determined to write CGI scripts in `bash`, at least do some google searches for "bash cgi" and "CGI security".  These pages look OK to start with:  http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/BashShellCgi.html and http://www.team2053.org/docs/bashcgi/index.html .  Finally, you might want to look at [bashlib](http://bashlib.sourceforge.net/) (note the page is ancient, source repository is now at https://github.com/dlc/bashlib)

Answer (score 1):

cas says, “This script has so much wrong with it
that I don't even know where to begin…”. 
Well, I have some ideas on where to begin:

- Please don’t ask us to debug your script and then post pseudo-code. 
  Your first code block contains backticks (`) in places
  where they will not work.
- Please be more explicit. 
  “I can’t get my if statement to work” isn’t very helpful to us. 
  What happens?
- You should always quote your shell variable references
  (e.g., `"$middle"`) unless you have a good reason not to,
  and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.
- `$(echo "$middle" | grep '.')` will equal `'true'`
  only if `"$middle"` equals `true`. 
  The output of `grep` is the *content* of the line(s) from the input
  that  match the pattern given as a parameter.
- **`.`** is a pattern that means “any character”,
  so `grep '.'` will match any non-blank input line. 
  To check for an actual period (**`.`**), use `grep '\.'`. 
  Note that this will match `W.` but also `.W`, `...`, `3.14159`, etc.
- Why are you doing a `while`? 
  Do you expect that code to execute more than once?  Do you expect it
  to get different results when executed repeatedly on the same data? 
  Where’s the end of the loop?
- **`-eq`** and **`-ne`** should be used only when comparing integers;
  use **`=`** and **`!=`** for strings.
- What do you mean
  by `-z STRING1 -ne STRING2`?

There may be other problems,
but my eyes hurt too much to look at this any longer.